# (Xcode) Linking dynamic libraries with correct paths

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dll, shared-libraries

I'm creating an OS X application in Xcode which is dependent on two dynamic libraries; GLEW and SOIL.
I link these by dragging them from "/usr/local/lib" to my project, and then adding them to the "Copy files build phase".

The libraries are successfully placed in the Frameworks folder inside the app bundle when building, but the executable is still looking for the libraries in "/lib/" and "/usr/lib/" which I discovered by using `otool` in the command line.

After many hours of searching for an answer I discovered that this can be fixed by changing the dylib's previous install names to the new locations inside the bundle using `install_name_tool`.
This becomes somewhat of a problem though when I rebuild my project, since the binary that I corrected is replaced.

Is there any way to tell Xcode that the libraries exists in @executable_path/../Frameworks/?

Comment: What do you mean by "running install_name_tool on the binary"? Did you change the install name on the original dylib, or in the bundled copy?

Comment: I changed the install name on the bundled copy to @executable_path/../Frameworks

Comment: Then you can either change it into the source copy, or automate the renaming after each build using a script in Xcode "Build phases".

Comment: But I am actually surprised that your method works at all, because the correct install name should be known at link time.

Comment: Welp, tried adding a build script and managed to break Xcode: `install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"`. Now Xcode crashes every time I run the project (even without the script) with the message "Xcode is damaged and can't be opened. Delete and download it again"

Comment: Lol yep.. I assume that's a bug in Xcode and has nothing to do with my script? I made sure `${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}` is correct btw. Oh well, I guess I'll settle with manually changing the install paths when I distribute my app for now! Thanks for the advice